# Yahoo messenger, which protocol does it use for VOIP/File transfer/Chat?

Tags: protocols, yahoo-messenger

I was wondering what protocol does yahoo use for VOIP,File Transfer and Chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, YIM uses a custom, propietary protocol, so unfortunately no XMPP.

Edit: Yes, they call it [YMSG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger_Protocol)